# Can't select or deselect checkboxes inside jQuery UI Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's dialog to show some options, each represented as checkbox. Now when I'm opening dialog, and clicking on checkboxes, nothing happens, checkbox doesn't get checked.I'm using jQuery UI's latest version.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong ?

Here's the code

```
$('div#attachedDocuments').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        title: "Select files",
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the dialog

```
<div id="attachedDocuments">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAttachments" runat="server"
                  OnItemDataBound="AttachedDocumentsDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxDocument" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of this problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: How can we know without seeing your code?

Comment: yeah you're right, I'm sry, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar issue. Here is what I thought was going on: jQueryUI will assign a `z-index` to the dialog when you call `.dialog()`. If you add more elements to the page after that, your dialog (or its contents) might become underneath something else (even something invisible). But then I saw [this bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6267), so I'm not sure about the cause anymore...

The solution: give your dialog a really high `z-index` on your CSS file, something like `99999`.

Comment: See [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271223/825789) for further info on this topic.