# Checkbox not checkable in dialog ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to solve a z-index problem with the jQuery UI Dialog, similar to question [Can't select or deselect checkboxes inside jQuery UI Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542327/cant-select-or-deselect-checkboxes-inside-jquery-ui-modal-dialog#comment13640659_10542422) , knowing there is a [bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6267) out there.

So in trying to up the z-index as recommended, I added the following code:

```
$('#interface').click(function(evform){
  $('#interface').prop('z-index')=99999;
});
```

where the chrome and firefox console.log states:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

HOWEVER, despite the error, the checkbox now works (throwing the console error every time).  If I remove the offending line, the checkbox becomes "unclickable".  How can I properly code this?

My HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Loading...">
    <p id="interface">Loading...</p>
</div>
```

(by the way, I tried adding inline style to the `<p>`, and it didn't work:

```
<p id="interface" style="z-index:99999">Loading...</p>
```

And with AJAX, I replace the contents of '#interface' with valid checkbox html such as:

```
<label for="right">
  <input name="right" type="checkbox">
</label>
```

and I have the usual jQuery/Dialog UI files included.

One final note, I tried to get creative, since this wasn't working and manually switch the checkbox by:

```
if ($(evform.target).prop('type')=="checkbox"){
      $(evform.target).checked;
}
```

*** EDIT UPDATE ***

As of December 22, 2013 (the EDGE pre release) of jQuery core, this bug has been fixed.  I hope they release the stable version soon (I beleive it will be v1.10)!  You can test it in a jfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/XXGQA/

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6267

Comment: Removed php tag since this question has nothing to do with it

Comment: This literally is not right: `$('#interface').prop('z-index')=99999;
`. The `99999` should be inside the `$.prop()` call as the second argument you send to it.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please, so that we can see much better what 's going on here? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @d_inevitable As I said on my answer to the linked question, I had a similar issue. It seems to be related to modifying the dom a lot after the dialog was init, then closing and reopening. But I found it difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry about the php tag!  I can't put a jsfiddle in easily, since I am loading several files with Ajax.  However, the sample in the bug report shows the same issue:  http://jsbin.com/ilofi3/5/edit#preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `z-index` on `#dialog`, not `#interface`.

Your code is throwing an error because you're trying to assign a value to a function call. So your code should be:

```
$('#interface').click(function(evform){
  $('#dialog').css('z-index', 99999);
});
```

Or just this on your CSS:

```
#dialog { z-index: 99999; }
```

**UPDATE**

This solution is not bullet-proof. The bug report filed for jQueryUI states that the problem happens if the checkboxes have a `z-index` lower than the overlay below the dialog. jQueryUI seems to be comparing z-indexes in an absolute manner, which goes against the CSS standard (but is understandable, considering a proper comparison would probably be resource-intensive).

So the actual solution may depend on which elements you're setting `z-index` (and `position`) inside the dialog. To avoid the bug, no not use `z-index` inside the dialog, or set a value guaranteed to be higher than what will be (dynamically) assigned to the overlay (hence, my  `99999` suggestion).

Comment: Thank you, @bfavaretto.  But when doing this, the checkboxes are still unclickable.  It seems that the console error did something to make it work.  I did verify through the debugger that the z-index was set with the CSS method above.

Comment: @SableFoste in that case what bfaveretto said in the comment on the question makes a lot of sense now... It is not the error that fixed it, but the portion that comes after the error and never gets run due to it.

Comment: Ah!, thank you @d_inevitable, I think you are right.  The problem is that I don't know what gets stopped, because it is buried in the jQuery API.  I might just need to figure another way around it.

Comment: Note: the original js code on my answer was using `.prop` like on the question. I just realized that wouldn't work for `z-index`, you have to use `.css`. Answer updated accordingly. But I still think the pure css solution is simpler. Anyway, neither option seems to be solving the issue...

Comment: @bfavaretto, you inspired me!  I figured it out, using a little bit of deductive coding.  In order to find out what the problem was, I wanted to find out what was higher z-index.  I will post the code in my answer below, but for a long story short, it was the 'return false;' that I had at the end of my click function.  I'm not sure why it broke it, but removing fixed the problem (along with the css you recommended).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#interface').click(function(evform){
  $('#interface').prop('z-index')=99999;
});
```

should be

```
$('#interface').click(function(evform){
  $('#interface').prop('z-index', 99999);
});
```

The second argument (if provided) sets the property to its value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback, @d_inevitable.  I did try this already, and the code "works" since it doesn't throw a console error, but the check box no longer functions.  It does function with my original code posted (which does throw a console error.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turns out to be the `return false;` I had in my click coding:

```
$('#interface').click(function(evform){
  *** did stuff here ***

   evform.preventDefault;
   return false; //This is the offending line of code
});
```

For diagnosis, I wanted to see what had a higher z-index on the page, so I added:

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if ($(this).css('z-index')>99) { 
        console.log ($(this).css('z-index')+", " + $(this).prop('class'));
    }
});
```

which gave me all elements with a z-index higher than 99.  It turns out that the ui-dialog was normally set to 1001 or 1002, so the '99999' listed by @bfavaretto was more than high enough.

Still don't know why the `return false;` created the error, but I hope the next update fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! You really can't `return false` from that function (it's not a jQueryUI bug). That will cause the "default event" on the element being clicked to be prevented (like you're doing with `evform` the line before -- in that case probably preventing a form from being submitted, right?). The default event on a checkbox is to toggle its state between `checked` and not `checked`. If you prevent it, the field becomes immutable. Note that even though you setup the click handler on `#interface`, click events bubble up, so your handler was catching clicks on the checkbox.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for helping me with the understanding... sometimes we just program by rote, and this is a good example of needed to really understand the underlying principles.